# No index.html in dist folder in angular8

Tags: angular8

Running `ng build --prod` command after update angularcli to version 8 does not generate index.html inside dist folder.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to ask here. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I had update my angularcli from v7 to v8 then i had create a new project, after build that project using --prod flag there is not index.html file generated inside dist folder.

Comment: @AadityaSharma Now it is clear to you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is solved, In angular 8 while I get an error of maximum budget exceeds it builds the dist folder but without index file,
while I increase my budget like below:

```
  "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                }
```

It works.

Comment: This solution helped me. Thanks

Comment: the index.html is generated. But why still can't deploy my website?

Comment: It worked, generating index.html file. But why "irebase deploy" didnt work for me?